# Convergence of the sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence

Let $u_n=\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log n}}$ then what can we say about convergence of the sequence and series as well... I tried Cauchy condensation formula but that doesn't seems to work...

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$(\log n)^{\log n} = n^{\log \log n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me give the condensation formula a try...

$$u_n=\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log n}}$$

$$v_n=\frac{2^n}{(n\log 2)^{n\log 2}} = \left(\frac{2}{(n\log 2)^{\log 2}}\right)^n$$

Now use the root test:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{2}{(n\log 2)^{\log 2}}\right)^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{(n\log 2)^{\log 2}} = \frac{2}{(\log 2)^{\log 2}}\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-\log 2} = 0 < 1$$

So it converges.